# Which post hoc test should I choose - Dunn's Test or Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon? Analysis of 3 groups of physicochemical data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

I am working on a scientific paper comparing physicochemical data from the river and two well rows (3 groups of data) - see example picture:

[image]

In my study, I want to see if there are statistically significant differences in the content of selected parameters (chlorides, sulphates etc...) between the a) river and row A, b) the river and row B, c) row A and row B.

I have already performed the Kruskal-Wallis test for the selected parameters and obtained p values < 0.05.

My groups have different sizes, for example, the river: 56 observations, row A: 77 observations, and row B: 44 observations.

Perhaps I should use some other tests at all? I am self-taught about statistics, and the choice of tests was dictated mainly by research on the internet.

I should add that I have already done Mann-Whitney, but today I found this post https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/dunns-test-post-hoc-test-after-kruskal-wallis/ saying "the appropriate post-hoc test that should follow a Kruskal-Wallis test, is Dunn’s test, not Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon." and now I am a bit puzzled.

PS.
I conduct my study in Python 3.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times --  search *kruskal-wallis post hoc* up in the search bar.  ... like so:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=kruskal-wallis+post+hoc  or look at the most relevant links in the "Related" section in the sidebar on the right ->  (the first few of those should have been offered to you when you tried to post your question)